# jQuery storing files lines to array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two .txt files that I am trying to create combinations from. I am trying to take the each file and turn them into an array as each word is separated by a newline. The problem is that when I run the `$.get` it does not save any information to the array. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email Validator</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="runtime"></span>
        <table class="results">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            //pull firstnames and store to array
            var firstnames = new Array();
            $.get('first.txt', function(data){
                firstnames = data.split("\n");
            });

            //pull lastnames and store to array
            var lastnames = new Array();
            $.get('last.txt', function(data){
                lastnames = data.split("\n");
            });

            var fn, ln;
            //firstnames
            $.each(firstnames , function(findex, fvalue) {
                fn = fvalue;
                //lastnames
                $.each(lastnames , function(lindex, lvalue) {
                    ln = lvalue;
                    $("table.results").appendTo("<tr><td>" + fn + "</td><td>" + ln + "</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.
When you want to depend on the result of multiple ajax calls, you can use `$.when`. One of the ways could be:

```
$.when(first, last).then(successCallBackFn, failureCallBackFn);
```

Where do `first` and `last` come from? Well, they can be the result of calling $.get like below:

```
var first = $.get('first.txt', function(data){
                firstnames = data.split("\n");
            });
```

Similarly `last`.

```
var last = $.get('last.txt', function(data){
                lastnames = data.split("\n");
            });
```

Finally, use $.when like below:

```
$.when(first, last).then(successCallBackFn, failureCallBackFn);

            function successCallBackFn(firstNames, lastNames) {
                var fn, ln;
                //firstnames
                $.each(firstnames, function (findex, fvalue) {
                    fn = fvalue;
                    //lastnames

                    $.each(lastnames, function (lindex, lvalue) {
                        ln = lvalue;
                        $("table.results").append("<tr><td>" + fn + "</td><td>" + ln + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                });
            }

            function failureCallBackFn() {
                console.log('failed');
            }
```

Also. note that you need to use `append` instead of `appendTo` in the line `$("table.results").append`.

Answer (score 0):

$.get() is an AJAX call and that means it is asynchronous. The data.split() line occurs whenever the $.get completes and not necessarily before the $.each block you have.

Since you need to make two asynchronous calls you can try embedding:

```
        //pull firstnames and store to array
        var firstnames = new Array();
        var lastnames = new Array();
        $.get('first.txt', function(data){
            firstnames = data.split("\n");

            //pull lastnames and store to array
            $.get('last.txt', function(data){
                  lastnames = data.split("\n");

                  // Process your two arrays here
             });    
        });
```